# EmguCV with Tesseract OCR fails to recognize even binary black-white single character images

Tags: .net, opencv, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

I am trying to get OCR working with Tesseract using EmguCV .NET wrapper. Because it didn’t recognize what seems to be very simple cases I went ahead and downloaded the command line tool itself [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Downloads.html) and confirmed it acted the same way as the Emgu wrapper so it is not the library’s fault, it seems to be the way I use it or the tesseract itself. I got the eng.traineddata from the official tesseract installation binary from the link above as well.

```
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200328
leptonica-1.78.0
```

My code sample:

```cs
         var testBitmap = Screenshot.MakeCroppedBitmap(LeftPoint, ScreenshotSize); // takes partial screenshot
         
         Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract(Tesseract.DefaultTesseractDirectory, "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default);
         ocr.PageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleChar;
         
         Image<Bgr, byte> emguImageOCR = testBitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
         Image<Gray, byte> emguImageOCRGray = emguImageOCR.Convert<Gray, byte>();
         
         emguImageOCRGray._ThresholdBinary(new Gray(235), new Gray(255));
         ocr.SetImage(emguImageOCRGray);
         ocr.Recognize();
         
         Console.WriteLine(ocr.GetUTF8Text());
         
         emguImageOCRGray.Save("this-is-what-I-tried-to-read.png");
         testBitmap.Dispose();
         emguImageOCR.Dispose();
         emguImageOCRGray.Dispose();
```

[image]  It thinks this is a dot. `.` Probably due to that literal dot above the Z.

[image] It thinks this is an `i`.

Those are just 2 examples. It also makes mistakes for full sentences, but not always. Some cases were correct. What am I doing wrong here? This has to be my fault, there is no way I am using this right.

**Edit:** I think the reason it doesn’t work is because my train data file was not trained with the font I am using in this example. I need to find a way to create new train data that includes the right font. I didn’t find any Windows guide yet, only Linux and only for Tesseract v3.x.

**Edit2:** I had some help with obtaining a train data with the desired font. I also added a gaussian smoothing step to reduce the graininess of the binary images. Sadly, the model still predicts just under half of case wrong. I don’t see how to solve this problem anymore with just CV.

Answer (score 1):

In your post, you talk about getting a tessdata file, which I assume you got from this github link here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata.

With the newest update for both Tesseract and Emgucv, a previously broken feature is now usable called the whitelist.

You create a function that can handle all OCR engine related values and functions, then just call it before you actually use it.

```cs
  public static void LoadOCREngine(String dataPath)
  {
     //create OCR engine
     _ocr = new Tesseract(dataPath, "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractCubeCombined);
     _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-1234567890");
  }
```

You pass the function the path to your tessdata file, then you can specify what characters you want to detect, ignoring all other characters. If you do get an error, I would suggest changing the OcrEngineMode to another available option.

Again from your post, the final image after being passed through all the filters looks pretty good, so I don't think it has to do with that, but in past experiences, just enabling the whitelist feature saw a huge spike in accuracy with Tesseract.